# How to fix: "Operation must use an updateable query" on update statement in Access VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to run an Update query in Access VBA to update a master table from a temporary change table. The tables are organized in the following way:

```
     Change_Table       
B_ID          Change       New_Value
111           Email         new@.com
222           email         new2@.com

Master_Table    
B_ID    Email
111    old@.com
222    old2@.com

Successful output:

Master_Table    
B_ID    Email
111    new@.com
222    new2@.com
```

I have made sure both tables have primary keys and the database/folders have full control permissions. The DB is local to my machine.

I have developed the following code to perform the update:

```
SQL = "Update Master_Table SET Email = (SELECT Change FROM Change_Table WHERE Master_Table.B_ID = Change.B_ID)"

DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

I keep getting Run-time error '3073': Operation must use an updateable query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JOIN tables instead of nesting.

`SQL = "UPDATE Master_Table INNER JOIN Change_Table ON Master_table.B_ID = Change_Table.B_ID SET Master_Table.Email = Change_Table.Email"`

Use Access query builder to get correct syntax then copy/paste from SQLView into VBA. Will often need to do some minor edits in VBA but it should get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try to run that code, I get Run-time error '3144': Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

Comment: BTW @gharold, it is better to save `JOIN` queries which will be more efficient than VBA string SQL calls as Access engine saves best execution plan.